# Printing lists without brackets and commas (python)

Tags: python

I need help with a list.
Here is the code: (This programm forms 5 combinations of the 3 digits you gave it)

```
a, b, c = input("Dati 3 cifre, separate prin spatiu (1xSpace) \t").split(" ")
list1 = [a]
list2 = [b]
list3 = [c]
comb1 = list1 + list2 + list3
comb2 = list1 + list3 + list2
comb3 = list2 + list1 + list3
comb4 = list2 + list3 + list1
comb5 = list3 + list2 + list1
list_final = [comb1, comb2, comb3, comb4, comb5]
print(list_final)
```

As you can see I have created some lists, al of them summing in one big list. But the programm needs to print these lists without any brackets and commas, only the numbers.

Comment: When you print a list, Python prints the brackets and commas. To print just the individual elements, iterate through the list and print the individual elements

Comment: Can you help me with the iterating, because i don't know how to do it. I'm new to Python

Comment: This is covered by any basic Python tutorial. It looks like you need to go through one of the many great tutorials available online or talk to a tutor. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for tutorials. Please take the [tour], and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and [ask]. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it looks like you are manually attempting to compute all possible permutations, if that is the case you can use `itertools.permutations`. After that to display the values with no braces or commas (which is just how python natively displays lists) you can iterate through and print each value manually.

```
from itertools import permutations
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

for i,j,k in permutations([a,b,c]):
    print(i, j, k)
```

Output

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: What is easier than a one-line for loop? It is certainly easier than the hand-written permutation approach you've written thus far.